# LINQ, where third nested children's property value is equal to something?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am having trouble getting this LINQ where to return any results, I've got several classes like this:

```
public class RestaurantMenu
{
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<FoodItem> FoodItems { get; set; }
}

public class FoodItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Given a list of `RestaurantMenu`, I am trying to return any matching results where the restaurant menu's menu item's food item's label match ALL strings from a list. Basically, you input the food you want to eat, and it's supposed to return any restaurants where they have ALL the things you want to eat. It's supposed to support multiple strings, but I can't even get it matching one string.

So assume the following:

```
List<RestaurantMenu> allRestaurantMenus = /blah;
List<string> labelOfFoodsDesired = /blah;
```

I tried doing it by chaining where expressions like so:

```
IQueryable<RestaurantMenu> query = allRestaurantMenus.AsQueryable();

        foreach (string foodItem in labelOfFoodItemsDesired)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.MenuItems.Any(y => y.FoodItems.Select(z => z.Label).Contains(foodItem)));
        }

        List<RestaurantMenu> matchingRestaurantMenus = query.ToList();
```

But it always returns no results, even when through debugging I am sure there is a match. How would I write this query?

Comment: I think whats wrong with your link call is that you are reassigning the query variable. So your query which has all of allRestaurantMenus gets set to null or an empty list.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no that isn't the case. Because of the deferred execution of a queryable object, I can construct the query like above and it wouldn't actually execute until I call to list. It would be no different than doing something like query.Where(x => Id == 2).Where(x => x.Id == 3).Where(x => x.Id == 4). It combines them into a single query of query.Where(x => x.Id == 2 && x.Id == 3 && x.Id == 4) before executing. Not that that would return any results because that's not possible, but just for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
allRestaurantMenus.Where(m => 
    m.MenuItems.Any(mi => 
        !labelOfFoodsDesired.Except(mi.FoodItems.Select(fi => fi.Label)).Any()))
```

*How it works:* we are filtering menus which have at least one menu item with all labels you passed. With [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
!labelOfFoodsDesired.Except(mi.FoodItems.Select(fi => fi.Label)).Any()
```

we produce set difference between desired labels and all labels of food items. If all desired labels exist in food items labels, then set will be empty.

UPDATE: If you should check any menu item (not single one) then query will look like

```
allRestaurantMenus.Where(m => 
    !labelOfFoodsDesired.Except(
       m.MenuItems.SelectMany(mi => mi.FoodItems.Select(fi => fi.Label))).Any())
```

*How it works:* approach is same as above, but you should check all labels of all menu items. That is done with [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which flattens collection of menu items into collection of all labels. Then, as above, you can build set difference between desired labels and all labels of all menu items. If set is empty, then menu satisfies your conditions.

TEST: Given following menus

```
List<RestaurantMenu> allRestaurantMenus = new List<RestaurantMenu> {
    new RestaurantMenu {
            MenuItems = new List<MenuItem> {
                new MenuItem {
                    FoodItems = new List<FoodItem> {
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Chocolate" },
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Water" }
                    }
                },
                new MenuItem {
                    FoodItems = new List<FoodItem> {
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Egg" },
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Ketchup" }
                    }
                }
            }
    },
    new RestaurantMenu {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem> {
                new MenuItem {
                    FoodItems = new List<FoodItem> {
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Water" }
                    }
                },
                new MenuItem {
                    FoodItems = new List<FoodItem> {
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Banana" },
                        new FoodItem { Label = "Peach" }
                    }
                }
           }
      }
 };
```

And following desired labels

```
List<string> labelOfFoodsDesired = new List<string>
{
    "Water", "Banana"
};
```

Query above will flatten menus to sequences of all labels:

```
{ "Chocolate", "Water", "Egg", "Ketchup" }
{ "Water", "Banana", "Peach" }
```

And then it will build set difference between desired labels and this flattened results:

```
{ "Banana" }
{ }
```

Thus second result is empty (all desired labels exist in menu), only second menu will match.

Comment: That's not quite exactly what I need, my apologies if I explained it poorly. The menus need to have all the foods desired, but it doesn't have to be a in single menu item, it COULD be in a single menu item, or it could be over several menu items, as long as they are all at one restaurant.

Comment: @DOTang no problem, updated query. In that case you should flatten all menu items into collection of labels and check if all desired labels exist in that flattened collection

Comment: That last one still returns zero results.I am updating my question to include sample data.

Comment: @DOTang just verified with sample data (updated my answer) - works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work. I'm sure that you could remove the `foreach` so that it's a single linq query.

```
foreach (var restaurant in allRestaurantMenus)
{
    var restaurantFoodItems = restaurant.MenuItems.SelectMany(m => m.FoodItems);
    bool hasAllFoods = labelOfFoodsDesired.All(lf => restaurantFoodItems.Contains(lf));

    if (hasAllFoods)
        yield return restaurant;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this combination of `Where` and `Except`-`Any`:

```
var allMatches = allRestaurantMenus
    .Where(rm => !labelOfFoodsDesired
        .Except(rm.MenuItems.SelectMany(f => f.FoodItems.Select(fi => fi.Label)))
        .Any());
```

`labelOfFoodsDesired.Except(allmenu-food-item-labels).Any()` returns `true` if one or more desired labels are not available. The `!` reverses the condition so it checks where all foods are available. It is efficient since `Except` uses a set  internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
allRestaurantMenus.Where(x => labelOfFoodsDesired.All(b => x.MenuItems.SelectMany(y => y.FoodItems.Select(a => a.Label)).Contains(b)));
```

Works by getting all the foods in that restraunt into a list then for all foods desired it checks they are in that list.